# How to upload a file to server with synchronous request?

Tags: iphone

My brain is just going to hang, I am working on same method for .....

OK, I am working on an upload code which will upload the file to the server, which is successfully working

now what I need as fallows:

started with an example-->suppose I have a file named file.txt, whose size is 30MB, when I read the contents of the file it will give me all the 30MB it contains. In the sendSynchronousRequest method I want to give request upto 10mb of data and aging calling the same thing unless it reaches at the last point of file. (in brief I want to use a loop to send the request part by part to the server

-I need to seed data with small small chunk of total file to the server 
-In server I need a relevant PHP to Append the contain and put in to one file at the end of request

so can anyone help  me a with a relevant php and objective c code ?

waiting for your quick response  !!!!

Comment: that will accept a block of data (even via a POST) then append that block of data to a file. It seems to me that you need some kind of client side app that will take a file and break it up into chunks, then send it to your web service one chunk at a time. However, it seems a lot easier to create an sftp dir, and let clients just sftp up files using some pre-existing client app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for the solution, create a multipart form request and do it via sync request.
as for the code, it will be little too much to post here :)

Comment: ok,i understand can you explain me how multipart can done for a request .

Comment: easiest would be to use ASIHTTPRequest foe this, it is a very good open source library. e.g for using: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use